# Tone and meaning of phrases that start with "I thought I said"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I have heard this phrase often when people are irritated if not upset about what had happened despite them making it clearer that they don't wish for it.

Eg:

1. I thought I said NO.
2. I thought I said no surprises
3. I thought we said no to puppies

What does the phrase mean actually? Does it always carry a negative tone with it?
The above examples obviously emit irritation to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is another one of those questions where translation into your language would produce the same result.

Comment: Have you seen no cases using, eg, I thought I said YES; 
I thought I said plenty of surprises; I thought we said yes, bring on the puppies?

Answer (score 8):

The tone is usually negative, and sarcasm is involved. When the TV that cost £1000 is smashed, and I say to my son, 'I thought I told you not to play football in the house', I am **pretending** not to be sure that I told him that.

Comment: That pretending is the irony of sarcasm, because you know you did more than think you said it.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - like saying to a waiter, 'I could have sworn I asked for steak' when he brings you fish. I am told by my American sister-in-law that some Americans call this sort of thing English 'snark' and don't like it. She's been here long enough to pick up the tendency.

Comment: Yes, we use that tone to fake 'taking it on ourselves': It must be me. This isn't what I ordered, but that's just me. Did I miscommunicate?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Although "I could have sworn" is actually a pretty strong statement and therefore void of sarcasm, or at least irony (can you have sarcasm without irony?). It may be used to actually express self-doubt. Like muttering to oneself "I could have sworn that I put my glasses on the desk (but cannot see them now, what's wrong with me?)".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - 'I could have sworn' can be used with or without sarcasm.

Answer (score 7):

It does **generally** carry a negative tone, but not always. One can imagine a young couple in love and one of them looking adoringly at the other, saying, “I thought I said I didn’t want any birthday gifts.” Here it might be intended to convey mild surprise, and perhaps infatuated gratitude. But that sort of example is probably the exception.

Comment: Ah, 'infatuated gratitude' - how fine it was!

Comment: Shameless steal from Frank Zappa - _Cheap thrills in the back of my car/Cheap thrills - how fine they are!_

Comment: Kind of a double irony (she knows she said it, and she is not mad even though she is pretending). "Bad boy!" --  "You shouldn't have!" would be lacking the first part, only pretending an objection.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers have talked about the meaning in your examples, but I just want to add that it can also **literally** mean what it says, that is "I was under the impression that I said something [but actually I didn't]".

For example, say I'm explaining how to set up a tent and I say, *"Now do the pegs like I said."* but someone replies *"How's that?"* so I say, *"Oops, **I thought I said** that already. They need to go in at a 45-degree angle."*

Or say I'm walking a customer through setting up some software, and they want to disable a specific feature. The menu to do that is confusing so they click the wrong option and I ask *"Didn't you want to disable that?"* so they say *"I enabled it? **I thought I said** to disable it! Darn menu didn't make any sense."* (And just in case it's unclear, "said" here doesn't literally mean "spoke out loud".)

Comment: Tone of voice is very important in distinguishing the two cases.

Comment: @Glenn And context in the second example here. Without the surrounding sentences, a frustrated tone on *"I thought I said to disable it!"* could be either at the menu or at me (if the customer misunderstood how the process works).